# Python object losing __dict__ after mixin injection

Tags: python, oop, mixins, python-decorators

I am trying to inject a mixin to a class with a decorator. When the code runs the class no longer has a **dict** property even though the dir(instance) says it has one. I'm not sure where the property is disappearing. Is there a way that I can get **dict** or otherwise find the instance's attributes?

```
def testDecorator(cls):
    return type(cls.__name__, (Mixin,) + cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))

class Mixin:         
     pass

@testDecorator
class dummyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testVar1 = 'test'
        self.testVar2 = 3.14

inst = dummyClass()
print(dir(inst))
print(inst.__dict__)
```

This code works if the decorator is commented out yet causes an error when the decorator is present. Running on python 3.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "losing `__dict__`". What's happening is that your original `dummyClass` has a `__dict__` [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) intended to retrieve the `__dict__` attribute of instances of your original `dummyClass`, but your decorator puts that descriptor into a new `dummyClass` that doesn't descend from the original.

It's not safe to use the original `__dict__` descriptor with instances of the new class, because there's no inheritance relationship, and instances of the new class could have their dict pointer at a different offset in their memory layout. To fix this, have your decorator create a class that descends from the original instead of copying its dict and bases:

```
def testDecorator(cls):
    return type(cls.__name__, (Mixin, cls), {})
```

Comment: Simply excising `__dict__` from the mapping passed to `type` also works (a new `__dict__` descriptor is created automatically).  Might be a good idea to also remove `__weakref__`.

Comment: Well, `Mixin` has its own `__dict__` descriptor, so it ends up using that one instead of creating a new one, but yeah, removing `__dict__` should work.